# pandas: Composition for chained methods like .resample(), .rolling() etc

Tags: python, pandas, chained, object-composition

I would like to construct an extension of `pandas.DataFrame` — let's call it `SPDF` — which could do stuff above and beyond what a simple `DataFrame` can:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def to_spdf(func):
    """Transform generic output of `func` to SPDF.

    Returns
    -------
    wrapper : callable
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return SPDF(res)

    return wrapper


class SPDF:
    """Special-purpose dataframe.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame

    """

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.df)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        res = getattr(self.df, item)

        if callable(res):
            res = to_spdf(res)

        return res


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # construct a generic SPDF
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(4))
    an_spdf = SPDF(df)

    # call .diff() to obtain another SPDF
    print(an_spdf.diff())
```

Right now, methods of `DataFrame` that return another `DataFrame`, such as `.diff()` in the MWE above, return me another `SPDF`, which is great. However, I would also like to trick chained methods such as `.resample('M').last()` or `.rolling(2).mean()` into producing an `SPDF` in the very end. I have failed so far because `.rolling()` and the like are of type `callable`, and my wrapper `to_spdf` tries to construct an `SPDF` from their output without 'waiting' for `.mean()` or any other last part of the expression. Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I am missing a purpose of `SPDF`. What it will give you a regular `DataFrame` is incapable of?

Comment: Could you show how do you arrive to your problem? Starting from your MWE, I'm cheking whether chaining methods returns an `SPDF` "in the very end" and getting the expected result (i.e. `isinstance(an_spdf.rolling(2).mean(), SPDF)` returns `True`)

Comment: @TomasFarias you are right! I simplified a bit and did not notice the provided MWE actually works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be properly subclassing `dataframe`. In order to get `copy-constructor` methods to work, pandas describes that you must set the [`_constructor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas) property (along with other information).

You could do something like the following:

```
class SPDF(DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SPDF
```

If you need to preserve custom `attributes` (not `functions` - those will be there), during `copy-constructor` methods (like `diff`), then you can do something like the following

```
class SPDF(DataFrame):
    _metadata = ['prop']
    prop = 1

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SPDF
```

Notice the output is as desired:

```
df = SPDF(np.eye(4))
print(type(df))
[<class '__main__.SPDF'>]
new = df.diff()
print(type(new))
[<class '__main__.SPDF'>]
```

Comment: +1 for pointing to _constructor. Still not perfect, but will probably become the way to go in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to subclass `DataFrame`, you can introduce another class like `PendingSPDF` and wrap non-dataframe objects with it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def to_spdf(func):
    """Transform generic output of `func` to SPDF.

    Returns
    -------
    wrapper : callable
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(res, pd.DataFrame):
            return SPDF(res)
        else:
            return PendingSPDF(res)

    return wrapper

class SPDF:
    """Special-purpose dataframe.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame

    """

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.df)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        res = getattr(self.df, item)

        if callable(res):
            res = to_spdf(res)

        return res

class PendingSPDF:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        res = getattr(self.df, item)

        if callable(res):
            res = to_spdf(res)

        return res

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # construct a generic SPDF
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(4))
    an_spdf = SPDF(df)

    # call .diff() to obtain another SPDF
    print(an_spdf.diff())
```